# Roll your own assertion (and do something fun with the methods)?

Tags: c#, assertion

I couldn't think of a way to describe what I'm trying to do for the question title--which may be why I couldn't just Google it. Any help either titling or Googling would be hot.

Here's the code I'm looking for:

```
Assert.That(true == false);
```

...or...

```
Assert.That(true == false).Else<ArgumentException>();
```

At this point, I can make the second one work *or* I can make the first one work. (The first one throws a very general "AssertionFailedException", which I would like to keep as the default in the event that the .Else() part isn't supplied.

Is there a way I can make these both work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, by the time `That` has been evaluated by the runtime, it doesn't know there is an additional method call (`Else`) to make. Frameworks like NUnit use a different syntax that avoids this problem:

`Assert.That(someValue, Is.Not.EqualTo(someOtherValue))`

You construct a constraint, pass it to `Assert.That`, then NUnit does the actual validation and exception throwing.

You could introduce a syntax like this (using NUnit again as an example):

`Assert.That(someValue, Is.Not.EqualTo(someOtherValue).Else<ArgumentException>());`

That way, configuring what exception to throw if the assertion fails is simply part of the constraint configuration.

Comment: Of course that's right. I was tinkering with having That() return an object, which would then have Else() as a method, but then I can't figure out how make it call its own default Else() (in the absence of an explicit call) without causing exactly the same problem again.